# Dynamically populate LI's inside last UL

Tags: jquery

I want to create something like this, but dynamically:

```
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="label1" class="col-sm-10 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Label 1</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="label1" placeholder="Label1" value="50">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="label2" class="col-sm-10 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Label 2</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="label1" placeholder="Label2" value="3">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="label3" class="col-sm-10 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Label 3</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="label1" placeholder="Label3" value="17">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

The amount of `li` items depends on how many rows it fetched from the database.

I tried something like this:

```
rows.forEach(function(obj) {
  $('#custom-fields').append('<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light"><div class="row"><label for="'+obj.id+'" class="col-sm-10 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">'+obj.label+'</label><div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="'+obj.id+'" placeholder="'+obj.placeholder+'" value="50"></div></div></li>');
});
```

...but I can't figure out how to wrap the `ul` around it. The thing is also that there are a lot of `ul`s on the page, so I can't simply use something like `$('#custom-fields ul').append('...`

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make, and append to, a new ul, and then append that to the page.

```
var $newUL = $('<ul>');

rows.forEach(function(obj) {
  $newUL.append('<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light"><div class="row"><label for="'+obj.id+'" class="col-sm-10 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">'+obj.label+'</label><div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="'+obj.id+'" placeholder="'+obj.placeholder+'" value="50"></div></div></li>');
});

$('#custom-fields').append($newUL);
```